# Use AVFoundation Still Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am taking a still image with AVFoundation like below and I am trying to use the captureImage (UIImage) to be displayed on a different view controller and no matter what I try that image captureImage wont display anywhere.  My question is that using that captureImage as is, is that a complete image that can be used and displayed anywhere?  I have seen a lot about AVFoundation camera buffer and im not sure if i need to convert that image to be used from a buffer to an actual UIImage.

```
- (void) captureStillImage
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                                            captureImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"photoTaken" object:nil userInfo:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture still image just for you to output image at capture time.
Use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to display like [AVCam code](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Classes_AVCamViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8)